Coordinate-wise projections separate points in the closed span of a sequence
Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb K$ where $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$, $(x_n)$ a linearly independent sequence (can be normalized with necessary or convenient) in $X$, $E$ the span of $(x_n)$ and $F$ the closure of $E$.
Let us suppose that the linear projection in the $n$-th coordinate $P_n:E\to\mathbb K$ given by $P_n(x_m)=\delta_{nm}$ is continuous (observe that the image of each element of basis and the linearity well defines $P_n$). Therefore, we can extend uniquely each $P_n$ to a continuous function (that will also label an $P_n$) from $F$ to $\mathbb K$.
In that setting, the set $\{P_n:F\to\mathbb K\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ separates the points of $F$? (That is, given $x\neq y$ in $F$, there is $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $P_n(x)\neq P_n(y)$).
Observe that I'm not assuming that $(x_n)$ is a basic sequence and neither that $(||P_n||)$ is bounded (what is equivalent to $(x_n)$ be a basic sequence).

Well, it's evident that the family $(P_n)_{n}$ separates the points of $E$, and $E$ is dense in $F$. Have you tried an approximation argument given some fixed $0 \neq z \in F$?

The answer is no; coordinate projections do not have to separate points in the closure, even if they are continuous. In fact, any infinite-dimensional Banach space contains counterexamples.
We will repeatedly make us of the following elementary fact: if $Y$ is a normed space with $\text{dim}(Y)\geq 2$ and $y\in Y$ is a unit vector, then there are unit vectors arbitrarily close to $y$ which are not in the span of $y$.
Now let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Pick a unit vector $x_1\in X$ and a unit vector $x_2\notin \text{span}\{x_1\}$ with $\|x_1-x_2\|<2^{-1}$. By Hahn-Banach there is a continuous linear functional $f_1\in X^*$ with $f_1(x_1)=1$ and $f_1(x_2)=0$. Then $\text{ker}(f_1)$ has codimension $1$ and is infinite-dimensional. Apply the above fact to $Y=\text{ker}(f_1)$ to obtain a unit vector $x_3\in \text{ker}(f_1)$, $x_3\notin \text{span}\{x_2\}$, with $\|x_2-x_3\|<2^{-2}$. Use Hahn-Banach to get an $f_2\in X^*$ with $f_2(x_2)=1$ and $f_2(x_1)=f_2(x_3)=0$.
Inductively, assume we have constructed unit vectors $x_1, \dots ,x_n\in X$ and functionals $f_1, \dots, f_{n-1}\in X^*$ with $\|x_j-x_{j+1}\|<2^{-j}$ and $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then $Y=\cap_{i=1}^{n-1}\text{ker}(f_i)$ is infinite-dimensional, $x_n\in Y$ and we may apply the fact to get a unit vector $x_{n+1}\in \cap_{i=1}^{n-1}\text{ker}(f_i)$, $x_{n+1}\notin \text{span}\{x_n\}$  and satisfies $\|x_n-x_{n+1}\|<2^{-n}$. The existence of the $f_i$'s implies that $x_1, x_2 \dots , x_{n+1}$ are linearly independent and we can choose $f_n\in X^*$ such that $f_n(x_n)=1$ and $f_n(x_j)=0$ for $j=1, \dots ,n-1, n+1$.
Continuing this process we obtain a Cauchy sequence of unit vectors $x_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and functionals $f_n\in X^*$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Similar to the previous paragraph, the $x_n$'s are linearly independent and the $f_n$'s are simply the coordinate projections. Let $x=\lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}x_j$. Then $x\neq 0$ and for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x_j)=0$. In particular the $f_n$'s do not separate the points of $\overline{\text{span}}\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
